# Squash git history

Tags: git

I have a large, old git repo with lots of binaries hosted on a local Redmine server. I'd like to squash all comments before the a certain date (either 6 or 12 months ago) together to save some on the size of my repo.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Any time you change any history, all commits after the change will have new SHA1 sums.  If it is just you using the repo, or a select group of folks that you can easily communicate with, then you can safely squash or filter (see below) to clean up history and then when they fetch, they'll need to manually reset all their branch heads to the new heads.  If this is *not* the situation, then you will just have to live with it, unfortunately.  Once history is published, it is not to be changed.

Now, you can remove commits using git rebase.  That's slow and painful, but it could work.  You could also use git filter-branch to remove all the binaries.  I had to do this on a repo myself and it's fairly easy.  If all of your binaries are in a single directory, then you can use the --subdirectory flag of git filter-branch (read the help page, of course) to remove everything from that subdirectory in all commits in the given range back through history.  If they are scattered, then you can give git filter-branch a shell command line, or a shell-script to execute on every commit and that script can go through and get rid of the binaries and whatever else you'd like removed or changed.  Again, see the help page.  But I think git filter-branch is definitely the way to go in this kind of situation.